# JBoss EAP 5.1, RestEasy/JAX-RS examples not working

Tags: java, eclipse, jax-rs, resteasy, jboss5.x

So while I know we should be coding for JBoss EAP 6 or even better JBoss EAP 7 - this is not always feasible and I am looking to add RESTFul functionality to a legacy JBoss EAP 5.1 production server.  The code/apps will eventually be migrated to JBoss EAP 7 but in the meantime JBoss 5 needs to be supported.

Using these examples:
https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/RestEasyInJBossDeveloperStudioJBDSQuickstart
https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/UsingTheRESTEasySimpleProjectExampleInJBDS3

I was able to get a JBoss EAP 7 version working as that's what the JBoss Developer Tools Git Repo examples are currently supporting - however, that could just be dropped into JBoss EAP 5.

I also found the jboss developer demos:
https://github.com/jboss-developer/jboss-developer-demos

But that's also only Jboss 7

I then found everyone's favorite MyKong example:
https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jersey-hello-world-example/

And also couldn't get that working.  I was just curious as to if anyone has any simple JAX-RS example that functions in JBoss EAP 5.  EAP 5 did hit EOL about 6 months back but I'm sure it'll still need to be supported for a bit of time.

Comment: All, I've figured this out and want to share the answer but I am having trouble formatting the code and XML. I shall follow up on this tomorrow!  Thanks you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after struggling for quite a bit - everything basically came together.  I performed the following.

In an existing or new Eclipse Dynamic Web Project  V 2.5...

- Create a new package with name "com.mycompany.examples.resteasy" in the source folder
- In the package create a class called "TestApplication" with the following code:

```
    package com.mycompany.examples.resteasy;

    import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
    import java.util.HashSet;
    import java.util.Set;

    public class TestApplication extends Application {

        private Set singletons = new HashSet();

        public TestApplication() {
            singletons.add(new Test());
        }

        @Override
        public Set getSingletons() {
            return singletons;
        }

        @Override
        public Set> getClasses() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }
    }
```

- Create another java class called "Test" with the following code:

```
    package com.mycompany.examples.resteasy;

    import javax.ws.rs.GET;
    import javax.ws.rs.Path;

    @Path("/")
    public class Test {
        public Test() {
        }

        @GET
        @Path("/test")
        public String test() {
            return "Hello RESTFul";
        }

    }
```

- Add/modify the following in the web.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5"
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

        <display-name>RESTEasy FileUpload Example</display-name>

        <welcome-file-list>
            <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
            <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
            <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
            <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
            <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
            <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
        </welcome-file-list>

        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>HelloRESTFul</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
                <param-value>com.mycompany.examples.resteasy.TestApplication</param-value>
            </init-param>
        </servlet>

        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>HelloRESTFul</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>

    </web-app>
```

- Clean and build your WAR, deploy.

If your applications WAR file is named "C1IPAuthService" you should be able to navigate to the following URL (If you're testing locally)
http://localhost:8080/C1IPAuthService/test

And receive the following output:
Hello RESTFul